# PHP parse array data using file_get_contents($url)

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have the following data I pulled from an API using PHP's `file_get_contents($url)`, I would like to parse this data and put each comma separated value into a variable whilst looping to the next set (there are thousands of row, I simply extracted the first two), I have tried parsing methods however most have an element consisting of the `datalabel:data`, any assistance would be gladly appreciated.

```
[[1610223840000,"3.63410000","3.65100000","3.62900000","3.64150000","14194.01000000",1610223899999,"51684.84892800",195,"7619.89000000","27756.15839400","0"],[1610223900000,"3.64610000","3.65090000","3.63410000","3.65000000","2219.73000000",1610223959999,"8090.68646600",46,"1176.75000000","4290.44934900","0"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured this out today, for anyone who needs it

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.blahblahblah";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[0] . "<br>";
     echo $value[1] . "<br>";
}
```